# WARN TaskMemoryManager:302 - Failed to allocate a page (16777216 bytes), try again

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing this error while running a spark job in standalone cluster mode.

I have following code in `pyspark`:

```
def join_client_info(self, cur_df):
        raw_clrr_df = sqlContext.read.parquet(hdfs_path+'/data/life400/CLRRPF')\
                                .selectExpr(['CLNTNUM as cliNum',\
                                            'CLRRROLE'])
        salh_df = sqlContext.read.parquet(hdfs_path+'/data/life400/SALHPF')\
                                .selectExpr(['CLNTNUM as cliNum',\
                                            'DECL_GR_SALARY as proposerSalary'])                                  
        spaceDeleteUDF = udf(lambda s: re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', "", s), StringType())
        clrr_df = raw_clrr_df.withColumn('clientRole', spaceDeleteUDF(\
                                    raw_clrr_df['CLRRROLE'])).drop('CLRRROLE')
        cli_num = cur_df.select(['cliNum']).collect()[0]['cliNum']
        number_of_pols_lf = clrr_df.filter('cliNum='+cli_num)\
                                        .where(clrr_df['clientRole']=='LF')\
                                        .count()
        number_of_pols_ow = clrr_df.filter('cliNum='+cli_num)\
                                        .where(clrr_df['clientRole']=='OW')\
                                        .count()
        with_lf_num_of_policies = cur_df.withColumn('numberOfPolsIn'\
                                                ,lit(number_of_pols_lf))
        with_lf_ow_num_of_policies = with_lf_num_of_policies.withColumn(\
                                                'numberOfPolsOw'\
                                                ,lit(number_of_pols_ow))
        # print(cur_df)
        with_proposer_sal = salh_df.filter('cliNum='+cli_num)
        return with_lf_ow_num_of_policies.join(with_proposer_sal,'cliNum','inner')
```

If I uncomment the `"print(cur_df)"` line, it works fine, doesn`t give me an error. I find this behaviour weird. What am I missing here?